# Round to 0.5 or 1 in ruby

Tags: ruby, rounding

Where `x` is any integer, I have a value about `x.1..x.4`. I want to round it to `x.5`, and if it is above `x.5`, say `x.7` or `x.8`, then it should round to `(x+1).0`. How is that possible? Is there a function in ruby?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `(v*2).ceil.to_f / 2` where v is your variable.

Comment: (v*2).ceil.to_f / 2 => (v*2).ceil / 2.0

Comment: @CodeGroover Whether to adopt your idea is up to mrd abd. If mrd abd wants to adopt that, then mrd abd will do so. Do not change the code in other peoples answer (other than for trivial things like formatting, removing extra part, etc.).